# Delete all records and all objects and all components from Developer Org

Tags: delete, refresh, developer-org

Is it possible to wipe out everything from your dev org? Everything includes all records (custom as well as standard), all components like classes, triggers, etc, all workflows, profiles and permission sets, all Users.

In short make my dev org as brand new blank org where I can start fresh.

The reason I want to do this is I do not want to have new OrgId and raise case with Salesforce to increase my limits on Custom labels. Also I will not have to re-setup my code repository.

I have checked [Permanent delete Custom Objects and Custom Fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46393/permanent-delete-custom-objects-and-custom-fields), destructiveChanges.xml but not sure whether this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

You can try to delete all of the Apex classes, Visualforce pages, custom objects, and other visible customizations. To do so, you'd need to construct a `destructiveChanges.xml` manifest, perhaps using a tool like the Force.com IDE (disclaimer: about to be end-of-lifed) to determine the full scope of metadata in the org.

But there are some things you cannot delete or reset in an org at all:

- You can't delete Users (you can deactivate them).
- Removing the first Record Type on any object is difficult and time-consuming (you have to unstitch it from all of the Profiles where it became the default).
- Some features cannot be turned off at all. [Person Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336884&type=1&mode=1), for example, is a one-way trip.
- There are still [quite a few things](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm) that are beyond the reach of the Metadata API, so any changes to those areas must be evaluated and altered by hand.

And there are other changes that you cannot delete and which don't have a factory-reset switch, like all of the `Settings` entities in the Metadata API. You'd need to manually review all of that feature-level configuration and reset it to what *you* consider an empty or starting state.